# Write shell script which runs the cygwin bash and executes a program

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, cmake

My problem is I´ve got no idea how to write this script and I haven´t found any description about the command which can be used!
So I´m trying to start the cmake-gui with a shell script (reason for that is to set the paths for cygwin in cmake)
If I´m running this bat:

```
@echo off

C:

chdir C:\cygwin\bin\

bash --login -i -c "exec ./cmake-gui"
```

the error is because I´ve got no idea how to use the -c parameter to change the directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain commands by separating them with `;`, (or `&&` or `||`, depending on your needs). So you'd write something like this:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin\
bash --login -i -c "cd /your/path/ && exec ./cmake-gui"
```

Comment: If I ´ve got any whitespaces in the path does it work with cd "/your/path" or anything similar?

Comment: Better use `&&` instead of `;` - cmake-gui will be started only if directory is successfully changed.

Comment: @Harner: Yes, just enclose it in quotes or escape the spaces and you'll be fine

Comment: @Andrey: True, I just realized I'd better edit that in after testing some nonexisting paths

Comment: After `cmake-gui` finishes, or as soon as it has started? (I've never used `cmake-gui`, but I assume it fires up some gui?)

Comment: As soon as the cmake User Interface has started the bash should close because it´s not necessary to keep it open. But when the shell executes the cmake-gui command it won´t go on to, for example an exit command, as long as the gui is open...?

Comment: You can append a single `&` afterwards, which will run it in the background: `bash --login -i -c "cd /your/path/ && exec ./cmake-gui &"`

Comment: The single & has the only effect that now when I close the bash windows the GUI closes as well. With a && closing the bash does only effect the bash. cd /your/path/ && exec ./cmake-gui && exit